# AngularJS: Inject strategies through dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, strategy-pattern

I am new in AngularJS DI, and I am wondering how to do things that I usually do in Ninject. I understand the limitations, so if it is not possible, a workaround will do.

I have to create objects that handle different event types, I usually follow the strategy pattern, and with Ninject in C# I can use multi-injection to inject an array of strategies in the constructor of my strategy broker.

The idea is that I would like to create more "handlers" (strategies) and add them to the AngularJS DI system, without alter common code. I have done this in JS before, by having an object where I can append the new strategies, but I wonder which is the right way of doing it in Angular.

Would be possible somehow in Angular to do something similar?